# How do I script a CSV Column Header with Special Characters in Powershell?

Tags: csv, powershell

I was building a powershell script to parse a CSV file. However, I found one of my column headers is written on Two Lines with a carriage return and new lines.

My column header is:
Invoice [New line carriage return]
Data

$spreadsheet.Invoice
Data

When I try accessing this column through the console, the script passes a carriage return & new line in directly to the input, but I can't include this in a Powershell Shell script. Is there anyway to access this column through a script.

Comment: `$spreadsheet.'Invoice Data'`

Comment: `$spreadsheet."Invoice\`n\`rData"` would be my guess.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that CSV formatting supported NL or CR characters.

Comment: I looked online at other posts. In theory it shouldn't but some people have had odd exceptions with new line data.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it. Instead of using Special Characters, if I actually put in an "Enter" Key in between strings, I can build the special characters I need. So my script becomes:

$row.Date = $spreadsheetRow."Invoice
Data"